# Adding time stamp values to a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have lately started learning SQL,and as a part of my assignment,I was trying to solve this question:
[image]
The table structure which I have created is:

```
CREATE TABLE train (train_no int,date_of_dep date,time_of_dep timestamp,time_of_arrival timestamp)
```

I am trying to insert a record for a train which will depart 33 minutes from now, and will arrive 115 minutes from current time.

This is the command I am trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO train VALUES(5,SYSDATE,TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE+33/1440),TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE+115/1440))
```

On displaying the table, it is giving me this output:
[image]

Can anyone explain why am I not getting the required output?

Comment: Okay let me edit my question

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I have replaced the pictures with text...please look into the question now

Comment: Despite the name `DATE` it always has date and time component. Difference between `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` is that `TIMESTAMP` supports fractional seconds, whereas `DATE` supports only seconds.

Comment: The answer for "Why I'm not getting ..." is: because [`to_timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_TIMESTAMP.html#GUID-57E09334-E3CC-4CA2-809E-F0909458BCFA) function takes string as input, so date expression gets implicitly converted to string with the default NLS parameters, which are some sort of `dd-mm-yy` by default (without time component). Then it gets converted back to timestamp without any time component. Explicit conversion between `date` and `timestamp` is `cast(date_value as timestamp`

Comment: Btw the table mentioned in the assignment will hardly handle departures at 23:59:59, so model with datetime columns will be not a workaround in Oracle, but a correct way to store this data.

Comment: @astentx But what about the values which I added to sysdate like 33/1440 and 115/1440....will they not get reflected in the timestamp?

Comment: As I've said, they were added to sysdate, but got truncated by implicit conversion to string.

Comment: So what correction can I do so that I get my desired output? @astentx

Comment: No correction is required, accepted answer is sufficient. My comment was about explanation "why" you get unexpected result: implicit conversion `date` -> string -> `timestamp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's no `TIME` datatype in Oracle, and as you need to collect information up to **minutes** (you certainly don't need fractional seconds; do you?), use `DATE` datatype as it contains both date and time information.

Also - although your task says that you do need it - you don't need *date of departure*; it is contained in *time of departure*.

Something like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE train
  2  (
  3     train_no          INT,
  4     time_of_dep       DATE,
  5     time_of_arrival   DATE
  6  );

Table created.
```

Insert a row; note that it is a good habit to specify all columns you're inserting into. You can add minutes the way you tried to, but - why wouldn't you use `interval`? It is easier to understand what you're doing:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO train (train_no, time_of_dep, time_of_arrival)
  2          VALUES (5,
  3                  SYSDATE + INTERVAL '33' MINUTE,
  4                  SYSDATE + INTERVAL '115' MINUTE);

1 row created.
```

OK, so - what's being inserted?

```
SQL> SELECT SYSDATE, t.*
  2    FROM train t;

SYSDATE    TRAIN_NO TIME_OF_ TIME_OF_
-------- ---------- -------- --------
11.02.22          5 11.02.22 11.02.22
```

Whoops! Not very useful. So - modify date format:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE, t.*
  2    FROM train t;

SYSDATE            TRAIN_NO TIME_OF_DEP      TIME_OF_ARRIVAL
---------------- ---------- ---------------- ----------------
11.02.2022 08:33          5 11.02.2022 09:05 11.02.2022 10:27

SQL>
```

That looks better.

Alternatively, you could have used `TO_CHAR` function with desired format mask:

```
SQL> select train_no,
  2    to_char(time_of_dep    , 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') dep,
  3    to_char(time_of_arrival, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') arr
  4  from train;

  TRAIN_NO DEP              ARR
---------- ---------------- ----------------
         5 11.02.2022 09:05 11.02.2022 10:27

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT]** If it must be a `timestamp`, you'd do the same:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE train
  2  (
  3     train_no          INT,
  4     time_of_dep       timestamp,
  5     time_of_arrival   timestamp
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO train (train_no, time_of_dep, time_of_arrival)
  2          VALUES (5,
  3                  systimestamp + INTERVAL '33' MINUTE,
  4                  systimestamp + INTERVAL '115' MINUTE);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT SYSDATE, t.*
  2    FROM train t;

SYSDATE            TRAIN_NO TIME_OF_DEP               TIME_OF_ARRIVAL
---------------- ---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
11.02.2022 08:57          5 11.02.22 09:30:35,783378  11.02.22 10:52:35,783378

SQL>
```

Comment: Your answer looks acceptable but can you tell me how would I have done this question in case I want to use TIMESTAMP datatype, which is present in ORACLE

Comment: Similarly to DATE; see edited answer.

Comment: @Littlefoot - I think you have a typo - in what was supposed to be an example of using TO_CHAR instead of relying on NLS_DATE_FORMAT, you actually showed TO_DATE . . .     ;-)

Comment: Gosh! Thank you, @EdS. I wrote "you could have used TO_CHAR" and - in code - used TO_DATE. My bad. Fixed.